# DRYing Function that multiplies array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dry

I have an array of 100 elements, that I have broken into 10 smaller arrays in order to quadruplicate the original 100 elements into an array of 400.

I am currently using :

```
function quadulator(arrChunks){
let a = []; 
let b = [];

    for(var i = 0; i< arrChunks.length;++i){
        a.push(arrChunks[i]);
        a.push(arrChunks[i]);
        b.push(arrChunks[i]);
        b.push(arrChunks[i]);
}  

return a.concat(b);

}
let group1 = quadulator(grid100[0]);
let group2 = quadulator(grid100[1]);
let group3 = quadulator(grid100[2]);
let group4 = quadulator(grid100[3]);
let group5 = quadulator(grid100[4]);
let group5 = quadulator(grid100[5])

let newArr = group1.concat(group2,group3,group4,group5);
```

This does exactly what I want it to do ,but Im looking for a way to eliminate the repetition.

The reason I am splitting it up into multiple parts is because I need the element of index 0 from the original array, to repeat itself in the indexes of 0,1,20, and 21 of the new array, along with every other element to follow this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve the `quadulator` function by noticing that `a` and `b` are the same. You can create a single array at once that represents both of them with `Array.from`, and then spread that array twice.

Then, with your `group`s, you can `map` grid100 by the `quadulator` function, and spread it into `[].concat` to flatten:

```
function quadulator(arrChunks) {
  const chunksDoubled = Array.from(
    { length: arrChunks.length * 2 },
    (_, i) => arrChunks[Math.floor(i / 2)]
  );
  return [...chunksDoubled, ...chunksDoubled];
}
const newArr = [].concat(...grid100.map(quadulator));
```

Demo:

```js
const grid100 = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16]
];
function quadulator(arrChunks) {
  const chunksDoubled = Array.from(
    { length: arrChunks.length * 2 },
    (_, i) => arrChunks[Math.floor(i / 2)]
  );
  return [...chunksDoubled, ...chunksDoubled];
}
const newArr = [].concat(...grid100.map(quadulator));
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: I am not familiar with some of the syntax you have used.  `{ length: arrChunks.length * 2 }`, the `(_,` and `. . .`  Other than that,it works perfectly, thank you. Edit: I have found the spread documentation.

Comment: `Array.from` is the functional way to create an array from scratch - the `length` property of the object passed in represents the length of the resulting array. `_` there is just a variable name, a name of `_` generally indicates that the variable isn't going to be used. `...` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which is similar to `concat` but terser.

Comment: sorry, it looks like I didn't understand what clicking the check did. Yesterday I believed I was accepting the answer but I guess I unaccepted it.Sorry!